# python pillow cant showing emojis that’s get from tweepy (twitter api)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tweepy

I'm currently programming a bot that copy tweets that mention on and paste it on image I'm using python , pillow , tweepy

when the bot get the tweet text from api and trying to paste it on image the emojis cant show on image , i tried a notocolor and other fonts but the issue doesn't fixed

also im using librqam because the main language of the project is arabic

```
import tweepy
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw , ImageFont
import requests
from io import BytesIO



CONSUMER_KEY = ""
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_KEY = ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)

auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY,ACCESS_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

mentions = api.mentions_timeline()
print(mentions)


for mention in mentions:
    tweet_id = api.get_status(mention.in_reply_to_status_id).id
    status_obj = api.get_status(tweet_id ,tweet_mode="extended")
    print(status_obj.full_text)
    save_id_inreplyto = status_obj.in_reply_to_status_id
    save_id_text = status_obj.full_text

    orginal_url = api.get_status(tweet_id).user.profile_image_url
    replaced_url = orginal_url.replace("normal", "400x400")

    response = requests.get(replaced_url)
    avatar = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    resized_av = avatar.resize((200,200))


    #print(api.get_status(save_id_inreplyto).profile_image_url)


    tweet = save_id_text
    img = Image.new('RGB', (1080, 1080), color=(178, 255, 233))

    ####
    # crop image
    width, height = resized_av.size
    x = (width - height) // 2
    img_cropped = resized_av.crop((x, 0, x + height, height))

    # create grayscale image with white circle (255) on black background (0)
    mask = Image.new('L', img_cropped.size)
    mask_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    width, height = img_cropped.size
    mask_draw.ellipse((0, 0, width, height), fill=255)
    mask.save('mask_circle.jpg', quality=95)

    #mask.show()

    # add mask as alpha channel
    img_cropped.putalpha(mask)

    # save as png which keeps alpha channel
    #img_cropped.save('dog_circle.png')

    ####
    twittericon = Image.open('twittericon.png')
    img.paste(img_cropped,(300, 100),mask)
    resized_ti = twittericon.resize((100, 100))
    img.paste(resized_ti, (300, 200))
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype('C:\\Users\\kmm\\Desktop\\fonts\\NotoSansArabic-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf', 30)

    d.text((280, 150), "@ "+api.get_status(mention.in_reply_to_status_id).user.screen_name, font=fnt, fill=(220, 180, 10))
    d.text((540,540),tweet, font=fnt, fill=(220, 180, 10),anchor="ms")

    img.save('pil1_text'+str(mention.id)+'.jpg' ,format='JPEG', subsampling=0, quality=100)
    #print(api.update_status_with_media(status="@"+mention.user.screen_name,filename='pil_text'+mention.id_str+'.jpg',in_reply_to_status_id=mention.id_str,tweet_mode = 'extended'))
    print("tweeted with media")
```

and this is the results images

[this one of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBMqE.jpg)

[this another result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDPP2.jpg)

[this original tweet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wagTI.png)   **as you see there's emoji that doesn't show in the result image**

Answer (score 0):

Your font does not support the usage of emojis. It is not an issue with pillow, you have to use another font.

Comment: i searched for fonts but if i found font thats support emoji its not support the alphabet and if i found one that support alphabet it dosent support emojis

Comment: Have you tried using two different fonts, one for the emojis and the other one for normal letters?

Comment: If you mean use tow d.text one for emoji and one for trxt I tried already but it dosent working will , if you mean merge 2 fonts no , im not trying yet